# How to set the value of a <p> element using Jquery and how to use a button to reset all objects of a certain object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So what I am given is this

```
<button id="restart">Restart</button>
<p id="score">Score: _ (_ dice with _ dots each)</p>
<p id="rolls">_ rolls left</p>
<div id="dice"></div>
```

and the goal is to set and update the values that are represented initially by the _ char, which will get replaced by the actual value. Creating a game akin to Yatzee, where the score is the sum of the dice with the most occurrance and highest value(ie, score is 12 if there are 2 dice that have 6 and no other most occurred dice value came up)

Using jquery, how would I set these values of the

element? I figured using

```
`$("#rolls").val(//some number);
```

However, that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: how about using `$("#rolls").text('something here')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to replace all instances of the "_" pattern with a value.  For example:

```
var value = 7; // An arbitrary example number
var element = $("#rolls");
element.html(element.html().replace(/_/g, value));
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Aside from the parentheses missing, the / is giving me an invalid regular expression error.

Comment: I'm so sorry about that - I incorrectly made the regular expression.  It should be just `/_/g`, meaning all instances of an underscore.  I fixed the parentheses, too.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately, the underscore is still present, no value is written anywhere where the underscore shouldn't be

Comment: Are you calling the code before the document is loaded?  If not, try wrapping what I provided in a `$(document).ready(function() { });` listener

Comment: everything is wrapped within a $(), which is similar to what you have written if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: I'm an idiot.  It should use `html` instead of `val`.

Comment: Would you know how to do score as well? Because each underscore is represented by a different value: the actual score, and 2 other different values for the other 2 underscores.

Comment: No problem!  Just keep in mind that once you call the code to replace the text in the `p` element, there will be no underscore left to replace if you decide to do it again.  This can be alleviated by caching the original, unmodified value.

Comment: Oh, that can't be good for my scores <p> element then. the values for those change according to the state of my program.

Comment: Sure!

You can use different values and a regex capure group:

`<p id="score">Score: {x}({y} by {z})</p>`

Then, in the JavaScript:

`var elementScore = $("#score");`
`elementScore.html(elementScore.html().replace(/(\{x\})/g, "value1"))`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3z10a46u/

Look at how I save the original source to the element using jQuery's data, and then use that to replace a more unique token in the code with a value in JavaScript.

Comment: So close. Unfortunately, this won't workusing multiple like so: {x}, {y}, and {z}
`code`
var elementScore = $("#score");
    elementScore.data("source", elementScore.html());
    elementScore.html(elementScore.data("source").replace(/({x})/g, totalScore));
    elementScore.html(elementScore.data("source").replace(/({y})/g, mostOccur));
    elementScore.html(elementScore.data("source").replace(/({z})/g, highestDiceValue));

also, I don't know how to edit code in comments. but the issue is only {z} gets changed proper. @samuel goodell

Comment: You can make it work by simply chaining the replacements.  replace(first thing).replace(second).replace(third) etc.

Comment: oh yeah, chaining is a thing. THXS

Answer (score 0):

If you have edit access to your HTML code, then you can do this -

```
<p id="rolls"><span id="rolls_val">_</span> rolls left</p>
```

and then

```
$('#rolls_val').html("Value");
```

**OR**

```
$('#rolls').html().replace('_', '<span id="rolls_val">_</span>');
```

and then

```
$('#rolls_val').html("Value");
```